# Probability problem about convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f’(a) \ne 0$. Let $\xi_n$ converges in distribution to $\xi$. Prove that $n(f(a+n^{-1}\xi_{n})-f(a))$ converges in distribution to $f’(a)\xi$.

Upd: It seems like it's possible to prove, that $n(f(a+n^{-1}\xi_n)-f(a))$ converges in probability to $f’(a)\xi$, if we rewrite it as $\int\limits_{a}^{a+n^{-1}\xi_n}f'(t)dt$, but I'am not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: You write in your update that you think you can prove convergence in probability. This can't be true because if you take $f(x) = x$ then $n(f(a + n^{-1} \xi_n) - f(a)) = \xi_n$ and $f'(a) \xi = \xi$ so you would have proved that convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks! I think that contradiction have just led me to some new approaches.

Comment: I haven't checked that this works but have you tried taylor expanding $f$? $n(f(a+n^{-1}\xi_n) - f(a))$ is of the form that when you taylor expand you get $f'(a)\xi_n + \text{h.o.}$ where $\text{h.o.}$ stands for the higher order remainder term which seems promising.

Comment: You might also try looking at Riemann sums for the integral you mention, since $f'$ is continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Rhys Steele comment, we can write $f(a + n^{-1} \xi_n) = f(a) + f'(a)\cdot n^{-1} \xi_n + h(n^{-1}\xi_n)$, so $n(f(a + n^{-1} \xi_n) - f(a)) = f'(a)\cdot\xi_n + n\cdot h(n^{-1}\xi_n)$. The first addendum converges in distribution to $f'(a)\cdot\xi$.

For the second, choose some $\varepsilon$. Choose some $X$ and $N$ s.t. for any $n > N$ we have $P(|\xi_n| > X) < \varepsilon$. Choose $\delta > 0$ s.t. for any $|x| < \delta$ we have $\frac{h(x)}{x} < \varepsilon$. Choose $M > \max(N, \frac{X}{\delta})$. Then if $n > M$, we have $P(|n\cdot h(n^{-1}\xi_n)| > \varepsilon) < P(n^{-1}\cdot|\xi_n| > \delta) = P(|\xi_n| > n\cdot \delta) < P(|\xi_n| > X) < \varepsilon$. So the second addendum converges in distribution to $0$.